# AngularJs - Execute Function in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My Web-App Should get images from server, show them and and give possibility to vote for Like it or Not.
Votes will be stored on DB.

my Controller :

```
$scope.beginSearch = function () {
    $http
       .get("http://example?q=" + $scope.search )
       .then(function (response) {
            $scope.url = response.data.data;
            });
};

<tr ng-repeat="x in url">
   <th>
     <img src="{{x.images}}"></img>
     <div class="well">
         <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-2x vertical-align" ng-click="vote_up(x.id)"></i>
         <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down fa-2x vertical-align" ng-click="vote_down(x.id)" ></i>
     </div>
   </th>
</tr>
```

I was hoping to use a function in every ng-repeat, which would return
votes for like

```
{{ return_vote(x.id)}}
```

But it doesn't work, and as far I see, I should not use functions in html,
if they are not in ng-click functions.

ng-init also doesn't work.

Could anyone provide me help, how could I solve my problem?

Images are on some website, I just get them by using their WEB-API, so they doesn't have API for votes, I need to do it myself.

Comment: what is behind `vote_up(x.id)`?

Comment: You need to provide your controller in this question. What you are asking for is possible, there are several ways to do it.

Comment: You need to share with us your controller, so we could help you. :)

Comment: Sorry I will do so :)

Comment: Since you can't have the votes in the API you could alternatively create a service to get all the votes at once and then create some logic to match them to images before rendering them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't have the votes in the API you could alternatively create a service to get all the votes at once and then create some logic to match them to images.

e.g.

```
$scope.images = [];
var votes = [];

activate();

function activate() {
    getImages().then(function () {
        getVotes().then(function () {
            matchVotesToImages();
            //Now we have a property 'votes' in each image object which we can use in ng-repeat
        });


    });
}


function getVotes() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('theUrl').then(success, fail);

    function success(res) {
        votes = res;
        deferred.resolve();
    }

    function fail(res) {
        console.log("Error");
        console.log(res);
    }

    return deferred.promise;
}

function getImages() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('theUrl').then(success, fail);

    function success(res) {
        $scope.images = res;
        deferred.resolve();
    }

    function fail(res) {
        console.log("Error");
        console.log(res);
    }

    return deferred.promise;
}

function getIndex(array, property, valueToCompare) {

    var i = 0;
    var len = array.length;

    for (i; i < len; i++) {
        if (array[i][property] == valueToCompare) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

function matchVotesToImages() {
    var i = 0;
    var len = $scope.images.length;

    for (i; i < len; i++) {
        //We pick need the votes of this specific image so
        var indexAtVoteArray = getIndex(votes, 'id', $scope.images[i].id);
        if (indexAtVoteArray != -1)
            $scope.images.votes = votes[indexAtVoteArray];
        else
            $scope.images.votes = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call your function inside brackets `{{yourFunction(x.id)}}` and add the logic to get the votes inside.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.url = [{
    images: "http://lorempixel.com/g/100/100/",
    id: 1
  }, {
    images: "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/",
    id: 2
  }]
  $scope.getVotes = function(id){
    //logic to get number of votes
    return id * 5;
  }
  
  $scope.vote_up = function(id){
    console.log("Vote up id " + id); 
  }
  
  $scope.vote_down = function(id){
    console.log("Vote down id " + id); 
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="x in url">
    <img src="{{x.images}}" />
    <p>{{getVotes(x.id)}} votes</p>
      <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-2x vertical-align" ng-click="vote_up(x.id)"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down fa-2x vertical-align" ng-click="vote_down(x.id)"></i>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes I did it how you wrote up here, but it does an infinite loop :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer.

```
$scope.vote_get = function (id) {

    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "vote.php",
        data: {
            'id': id
        },
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

    })
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
};
```

When I used this function to get votes, or return anything
, It does infinite loop. 
Maybe I'am trying to do in wrong way, then please give me tips how to do that.
I'am just sure, that I need to send ID of image to .php file, this file will connect to database and return votes for provided ID.

Vote_up and Vote_down functions are same, they just POST data but seem to work ok.

Thanks

So, no one has idea :(?